# Postman proxy not working for HTTPS requests

Tags: proxy, postman, certificate

I followed the instructions by Postman to set up proxy for HTTPS.  It's working fine for HTTP requests, but is not working for HTTPS requests.  I assume there is some issue with postman-proxy-ca.crt but I can't figure out what.
I'm on Windows and I've already tried the following:

- Deleted the AppData\Roaming\Postman\proxy folder, restarted Postman, reinstalled the cert, restarted Postman.
- Tried removing certs from Windows cert manager.
- Confirmed this works with HTTP requests

Any ideas how to get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must also install postman postman-proxy-ca.crt on the test device . example: iphone or android phone

Answer (score 1):

You can disable `SSL certificate verification` from File > Settings > General